# What is the best approach for positioning and overlaying images in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a map as a bitmap, on top of which I add markers - which can have different icons of different sizes, which contain data, and have various other options. The map is an image, and the way it's implemented now, is redrawing the map's area at certain position, with marker icons by iterating over the picture and setting pixels one by one using marker's image. But I realize this is probably not the best option avaiable so I am asking here.

I was thinking about using markers as controls, but I am not sure how I would accurately and programatically get and set the markers positions.

Comment: You could use a [`Canvas`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.canvas?view=netframework-4.8) to position elements and use the [Panel.ZIndex](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.panel.zindex?view=netframework-4.8) property to control the order in which they overlay.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A usual pattern followed in WPF apps is MVVM - you should have a look at online resources to get familiar with it and how it can leverage the power of WPF.

**To answer your specific problem**, you would build your app in a way that is data-driven: you create and expose a collection of markers as data objects and you bind the view to this collection by telling how an individual marker should be displayed.

Let's create a `MarkerViewModel` class that will contain all information the view needs to display them:

```cs
public class MarkerViewModel {
    public double X { get; set; }
    public double Y { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

Your `MainWindow` code-behind could be:

```cs
public partial class MainWindow : Window {
    public MainWindow() {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = new ObservableCollection<MarkerViewModel> {
            new MarkerViewModel() { X = 30, Y = 30},
            new MarkerViewModel() { X = 100, Y = 20},
            new MarkerViewModel() { X = 100, Y = 150}
        };
    }
}
```

We put some data in a collection (of type `ObservableCollection`) and assigned it to the `DataContext` property of the `MainWindow`.

Its XAML could be:

```xml
<Grid>
    <Image Source="Chrysanthemum.jpg" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
    <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top">
        <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <Canvas />
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="ContentPresenter">
                <Setter Property="Canvas.Left" Value="{Binding X}" />
                <Setter Property="Canvas.Top" Value="{Binding Y}" />
            </Style>
        </ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:MarkerViewModel}">
                <StackPanel>
                    <Ellipse Width="10"
                             Height="10"
                             Fill="Blue"/>
                    <TextBlock FontWeight="Bold" Text="{Binding Description}"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ItemsControl>
</Grid>
```

The `Grid` is here to overlay its two children: an `Image` which is the background picture and could be your base map, and an `ItemsControl` whish is repsonsible for displaying a view for each item in the `DataContext` collection.

The `ItemsControl.ItemTemplate` property lets you tell WPF how you want each marker displayed: I chose here a blue `Ellipse` and a `TextBlock`.

The `ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle` lets you tell WPF where you want to position each item it creates (it can do much more).

[image: Screenshot of picture with overlayed markers]

I suggest you start reading some tutorials [on data binding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop-wpf/data/data-binding-overview), [styling and templating](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/data/data-templating-overview) and [`ItemsControl` specifically](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/data/data-templating-overview#styling-and-templating-an-itemscontrol). Also read more on the MVVM pattern, but hopefully my example will help you get kickstarted.